# No csrf token for Django web page

Tags: python, django

I have a new Django app with REST endpoints and static html page that triggers `XMLHttpRequest` REST queries. POSTs fail with "CSRF cookie not set.".

If I open a client debugger, document.cooke returns "". AFAIK, this should have "csrftoken".

In *settings.py*, `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` contains `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` by default. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Does the html page have `{% csrf_token %}` inside the form?

Comment: No, but my Javascript code has `xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", Cookies.get('csrftoken'));' to use the cookie token. That works when the cookie is set.

Comment: How is the cookie value being set?  Using the example of a login page, one would first call GET on the page, which allows the server to set the cookie value; then one would call POST on the same page.  If you're calling POST with no prior traffic, the cookie never gets set.

Comment: I believe Django is expecting csrf_token to be an actual submitted form field, not in a HTTP header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ensure_csrf_cookie decorator to your view.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie

If that doesn't help you might want to read these docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax